# Time/JavaAPI - вычисление остатка двух дат

Tags: java

Как вычислить остаток между двумя датами, что бы их можно было выводить в таком формате:

```
Ivanov Ivan (Java Developer) - Обучение не закончено. До окончания осталось 1 д 6 ч.
Petrov Petr (J2EE Developer) - Обучение закончено. После окончания прошло 3 ч. 3
```

Мне только интересно вот эти данные "`1д. 6ч.`" и "`3ч.`"

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

В Java 8 есть только методы `toDays/Hours/Minutes`, число, которое они возвращают - это полное число дней/часов/минут в разнице, т.е. при разнице между датами 36 часов метод `toHours` вернет вам `36`, а вы наверное хотите 12, потому из `36` можно отдельно выделить целые сутки, соответственно нужно делать как-то так:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(startLocalDateTime, endLocalDateTime);
long days = duration.toDays();
long hours = duration.toHours() % 24L;
long minutes = duration.toMinutes() % (24L * 60L);
System.out.println((days != 0 ? days + " д. " : "") +
                   (hours != 0 ? hours + " ч. " : "") +
                   (minutes != 0 ? minutes + " м. " : ""));
```

В Java >= 9 появились методы `toDaysPart/HoursPart/MinutesPart`, в случае разницы в `36` часов `toHours` вернет вам как раз `12`, получится немного проще:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(startLocalDateTime, endLocalDateTime);
long days = duration.toDaysPart();
long hours = duration.toHoursPart();
long minutes = duration.toMinutesPart();
System.out.println((days != 0 ? days + " д. " : "") +
                   (hours != 0 ? hours + " ч. " : "") +
                   (minutes != 0 ? minutes + " м. " : ""));
```